# Flutter google_ml_kit - how to keep only the text recognition module

Tags: flutter, dart, ocr, google-mlkit, text-recognition

I've downloaded [Google's machine learning kit example](https://github.com/flutter-ml/google_ml_kit_flutter/tree/master).

My app only requires the text recognition module, so I'd like to remove the code for all the other features (barcode scanning, face recognition, etc.). How can I do that without breaking the example code? I'm using Visual Studio Code, and I'm new to to Flutter/Dart.

Thanks!

Comment: You could consider asking this question in that github repo as well to get attention from the authors. (BTW, as mentioned in the repo, this plugin is not sponsored or maintained by Google.)